# PRISM navigate to another View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

I have a MainWindow which only contains the region for displaying other Views:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion"/>
```

What I am trying to do, is to immediately when my `MainWindowViewModel` loads, to navigate to `MainPageViewModel`.

I have tried to implement interface `INavigationAware` such as following:

```
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", App.Experiences.DetailPage.ToString());
    }

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", App.Experiences.DetailPage.ToString());
    }
```

But even when I set my breakpoints over these, they are never executed.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Maybe I need to change my Bootstrapper logic? Here is how it looks like:

```
public class Bootstrapper: UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.TryResolve<MainWindow>();
    }
    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();

    }
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        Container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataRepository), typeof(DataRepository), null,new Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());


        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>(App.Experiences.MainPage.ToString());
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<DetailPage>(App.Experiences.DetailPage.ToString());


    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is, when the app loads navigate to the App.Experiences.DetailPage, right? Also, OnNavigatedTo/From are called when you navigate to/from the page. You have to call the region.RequestNavigate in some form of event (button click, etc.)

Comment: I can surely do it via button click, but I am trying to automatically load the appropriate (default) view upon my application initializes

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit my Bootstrapper logic such as following:

```
    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();

        Prism.Regions.IRegionManager newRegion = Container.TryResolve<Prism.Regions.IRegionManager>();
        newRegion.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", App.Experiences.MainPage.ToString());
    }
```